# Using forEach on a nested object key react javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I have a nested object:

```
const refsObject = {
  refOne: {
    current: {
      validate: function()
    }
  },
  refTwo: {
    current: {
      validate: function()
    }
  }
};
```

I need to run input field validation using a single method that loops through each nested object of objects and **invokes the validate method**.

What I have tried up until now:

```
const splitObject = o => Object.keys(o).map(e => ({ [e]: o[e] }));
splitObject.forEach(ref => ref.current && ref.current.validate());
```

SplitObject returns me an array of objects with all the objects inside `refsObject`. Once I do forEach on splitObject it becomes undefined since ref.current is inside the nested object key "**refOne**" which is dynamic so I cannot hardcode. Any suggestion helps!

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: forEach method doesn't return any value, better .map or .reduce

Comment: @OriDrori, I just need to invoke the method inside the current of each nested object containing input field ref.

Comment: `for (const { current: { validate } } of Object.values(refsObject)) validate();`, or if you need `this`, or don't like the way destructuring looks, `for (const v of Object.values(refsObject)) v.current.validate();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
  const refsObject = {
    refOne: {
      current: {
        validate: function() {
          console.log('validate1');
        }
      }
    },
    refTwo: {
      current: {
        validate: function() {
          console.log('validate2');
        }
      }
    }
  };

  Object.values(refsObject).map(refs => refs.current.validate());
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I just need to add refs.current && refs.current.validate()

Answer (score 0):

Run the validations on the original `refsObject` by taking the values, and iterating them with `Array.forEach()`. Use conditional chaining `?.` to call the function in case `current` might be `undefined`:

```js
const refsObject = {refOne:{current:{validate(){console.log('refOne')}}},refTwo: {current: {validate() {console.log('refTwo')}}}};

const runValidations = o => Object.values(o)
  .forEach(ref => ref.current?.validate());

runValidations(refsObject);
```